React: when an element in an array gets deleted, all subsequent elements gets re-rendered, while the previous don't
In this project (React with NextJS), the user can see various statistics, statistics like how many orders a certain rider made, how many hours it worked and so on. The user is not limited to just one "section", they can add and remove as many sections as they want so that they compare, for example, the stats of a certain rider vs another rider. The code here represents the page where these sections are shown. The key is that I have a useState containing an array of "Stats" nodes (the dialogs I talked about):
export default function Layout({ riders }: { riders: Rider[] }) {
  const [results, setResults] = useState<
    { index: number; data: StatsType[] }[]
  >([]);

  function onResult(result: StatsType[], index: number) {
    setResults((prevResults) => {
      const existingResultIndex = prevResults.findIndex(
        (item) => item.index === index
      );

      if (existingResultIndex !== -1) {
        return prevResults.map((item, i) =>
          i === existingResultIndex ? { ...item, data: result } : item
        );
      } else {
        return [...prevResults, { index, data: result }];
      }
    });
  }

  const [stats, setStats] = useState<ReactNode[]>([
    <Stats key={0} riders={riders} onResult={onResult} index={0} />,
  ]);

  const handleAddStats = () => {
    const newStats = [
      ...stats,
      <Stats
        riders={riders}
        onResult={onResult}
        index={stats.length}
        key={stats.length}
      />,
    ];
    setStats(newStats);
  };

  const handleRemoveStats = (indexToRemove: number) => {
    if (stats.length > 1) {
      const newStats = stats.filter((_, index) => index !== indexToRemove);
      setStats(newStats);

      setResults((prevResults) => {
        const updatedResults = prevResults.filter(
          (item) => item.index !== indexToRemove
        );
        return updatedResults.map((result, index) => ({
          ...result,
          index: index,
        }));
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-12 items-center justify-center">
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-4xl mt-8 w-full text-center">Statistiche</h1>
        {results && results.length !== 0 && <GraphDialog results={results} />}
      </div>
      <div className="flex w-full flex-wrap gap-y-8 justify-between">
        {stats.map((stat, index) => (
          <div className="relative w-[49%] group" key={index}>
            {stat}
            <X
              onClick={() => handleRemoveStats(index)}
              size={36}
              className="absolute top-[-1rem] right-[-1rem] invisible 
              group-hover:visible hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-opacity-50 hover:bg-white rounded-full p-1"
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <div
          className={`${
            stats.length % 2 === 0 ? "w-full" : "w-[49%]"
          } flex items-center justify-center`}
        >
          <Button className="" onClick={handleAddStats}>
            <Plus className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
            Aggiungi statistica
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

And now that Stats component:
export default function Stats({
  riders: receivedRiders,
  index,
  onResult,
}: {
  riders: Rider[];
  index: number
  onResult: (result: StatsType[], index: number) => void;
}) {
  const riders = receivedRiders;
  const [rider, setRider] = useState<string>("all");
  const [date, setDate] = useState<DateRange>();
  const [context, setContext] = useState<string>("all");

  function handlePresetSelect(value: string) {
    switch (value) {
      case "today":
        setDate({ from: new Date(), to: new Date() });
        break;
      case "yesterday":
        setDate({ from: subDays(new Date(), 1), to: subDays(new Date(), 1) });
        break;
      case "last7":
        setDate({ from: subDays(new Date(), 6), to: new Date() });
        break;
      case "last30":
        setDate({ from: subDays(new Date(), 29), to: new Date() });
        break;
      case "thisMonth":
        setDate({ from: startOfMonth(new Date()), to: endOfMonth(new Date()) });
        break;
      case "thisYear":
        setDate({ from: startOfYear(new Date()), to: endOfYear(new Date()) });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center p-6 w-[100%] gap-8 border- border rounded-lg">

      <div>{index}</div>

      <div className="flex items-center gap-8 w-full">
        <Select onValueChange={setRider} defaultValue="all">
          <div className="space-y-2 w-1/3">
            <Label htmlFor="rider">Chi?</Label>
            <SelectTrigger id="rider">
              <SelectValue placeholder="Seleziona un ragazzo" />
            </SelectTrigger>
          </div>

          <SelectContent id="rider">
            <SelectItem key={0} value={"all"} defaultChecked={true}>
              Tutti
            </SelectItem>
            {riders.map((rider) => (
              <SelectItem
                key={rider.id}
                value={rider.id.toString() + "-" + rider.nickname}
              >
                {rider.name + " " + rider.surname + " ("}
                <strong>{rider.nickname}</strong>)
              </SelectItem>
            ))}
          </SelectContent>
        </Select>

        <div className="space-y-2 w-1/2">
          <Label htmlFor="date">Data</Label>
          <Popover>
            <PopoverTrigger asChild>
              <Button
                id="date"
                variant={"outline"}
                className={cn(
                  "w-full justify-start text-left font-normal",
                  !date && "text-muted-foreground"
                )}
              >
                <CalendarIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                {date ? (
                  date.from && date.to ? (
                    `${format(date.from, "PPP", {
                      locale: it,
                    })} - ${format(date.to, "PPP", { locale: it })}`
                  ) : (
                    <span>Seleziona la data</span>
                  )
                ) : (
                  <span>Seleziona la data</span>
                )}
              </Button>
            </PopoverTrigger>
            <PopoverContent className="flex w-auto flex-col space-y-2 p-2">
              <Select
                onValueChange={(value) => {
                  handlePresetSelect(value);
                }}
              >
                <SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectValue placeholder="Date veloci" />
                </SelectTrigger>
                <SelectContent position="popper">
                  <SelectItem value="today">Oggi</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="yesterday">Ieri</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="last7">Ultimi 7 giorni</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="last30">Ultimi 30 giorni</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="thisMonth">Questo mese</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="thisYear">Questo'anno</SelectItem>
                </SelectContent>
              </Select>
              <div className="rounded-md border">
                <Calendar
                  locale={it}
                  mode="range"
                  selected={date}
                  onSelect={setDate}
                  numberOfMonths={1}
                  //onDayTouchStart={(e) => console.log(e)}
                />
              </div>
            </PopoverContent>
          </Popover>
        </div>

        <Select onValueChange={setContext} defaultValue="all">
          <div className="space-y-2 w-1/3">
            <Label htmlFor="context">Cosa?</Label>
            <SelectTrigger id="context">
              <SelectValue placeholder="Seleziona un contesto" />
            </SelectTrigger>
          </div>

          <SelectContent>
            <SelectItem key={1} value={"all"} defaultChecked={true}>
              Tutto
            </SelectItem>
            <SelectItem key={2} value={"orders"}>
              Consegne
            </SelectItem>
            <SelectItem key={3} value={"time"}>
              Ore
            </SelectItem>
            <SelectItem key={4} value={"money"}>
              Incassi
            </SelectItem>
          </SelectContent>
        </Select>
      </div>

      {rider !== "all" && date?.from && date?.to && (
        <StatsResult
          riderId={parseInt(rider.split("-")[0])}
          date={date}
          index={index}
          context={context}
          isAllRiders={false}
          onResult={onResult}
        />
      )}

      {rider === "all" && date?.from && date?.to && (
        <StatsResult
          date={date}
          index={index}
          context={context}
          isAllRiders={true}
          onResult={onResult}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

Stats uses "StatsResult", which is the component that will actually show the results (just a small table with the results)
export default function StatsResult({
  index,
  riderId,
  date,
  context,
  isAllRiders,
  onResult,
}: {
  index: number;
  riderId?: number;
  date: DateRange | undefined;
  context: string;
  isAllRiders: boolean;
  onResult: (result: StatsType[], index: number) => void;
}) {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<StatsType[]>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const body = isAllRiders
      ? { date, context, isAllRiders: true }
      : { riderId, date, context, isAllRiders: false };

    fetch("/api/stats/get", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then((result) => {
          setResult(result);
          onResult(result, index);
          setLoading(false);
        });
      }
    });
  }, [riderId, date, context, isAllRiders]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full overflow-y-auto max-h-[500px]">
      {date && result && result.length !== 0 ? (
        <Table className="w-full text-2xl">
          <TableHeader className="sticky top-0 z-10 bg-background">
            <TableRow>
              {result.some((item) => item.riderName !== undefined) && (
                <TableHead className="w-[25%]">Ragazzo</TableHead>
              )}
              {result.some((item) => item.totalOrders !== undefined) && (
                <TableHead className="w-[25%]">Consegne</TableHead>
              )}
              {result.some((item) => item.totalHours !== undefined) && (
                <TableHead className="w-[25%]">Ore</TableHead>
              )}
              {result.some((item) => item.totalMoney !== undefined) && (
                <TableHead className="w-[25%]">Guadagno</TableHead>
              )}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {result.map((item, index) => (
              <TableRow key={index}>
                <TableCell>{item.riderName}</TableCell>
                {item.totalOrders !== undefined && (
                  <TableCell>{item.totalOrders}</TableCell>
                )}
                {item.totalHours !== undefined && (
                  <TableCell>{item.totalHours}</TableCell>
                )}
                {item.totalMoney !== undefined && (
                  <TableCell>{item.totalMoney}€</TableCell>
                )}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      ) : loading ? (
        <BarLoader color="#36d7b7" loading={loading} width={"100%"} />
      ) : (
        <h1 className="w-full text-center text-4xl overflow-y-hidden">
          Nessun risultato!
        </h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

Now the problem:
Let's say I have 4 Stats components on my page and they all have some result inside. Whenever I try to delete for example the 2nd one, it'll actually get deleted and removed from the page (and from the state), but all the subsequent ones will get re-rendered and lose their result "graphically" (their actual result is still available in the results state). They are still present on the page, but everything that the user put and what was shown is just lost. The 1st instead, will remain intact.
Another example: I have 4 Stats with some result inside, I delete the 3rd, 1st and 2nd will remain the same, 3rd gets correctly removed, 4th gets re-rendered and lose their result.
I tried everything. I thought "Maybe some states I use in the Stats component are changing" but no. I debugged every single variable I could debug. I also tried using "memo" as this post suggests but no luck (if this is indeed the solution, I'd still very much appreciate the correct way to do it in my case).
My only theory is that this problem has something to do with either the index prop or the key property every Stats component has. Weirdly, only the subsequent components from the one I deleted get changed, and not the ones before. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the handleRemoveStats function? Somehow setting a new array breaks everything?
Another problem I noticed is that when I delete a Stats component, the key property of said component doesn't change. This also creates weird cases where if I delete a Stats and then add a new one, potentially two or more Stats will have the same key which may break things (?). The exact thing happens with the prop index.
The project's almost done but I can't get this "delete" functionality to work. I appreciate any help anybody can provide. Thanks!


Don't use index as key (https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys).
Read link fully before proceeding.
Create a new array every time you add / remove and item (you are already doing that but make sure the stats that remain have the same key as the old array)

for keys it has to be unique to each stat for all time. When you remove an item for example all the ones after it will get key = prevIndex - 1 if they stayed the same key as before they wont re-render - thats why the ones before delete index don't re-render
Usually that key is provided by the backend (row primary key and is usually a UUID) but it sounds like your rider data is hard coded you can just use time stamp concatenated with the rider ids in each stat for now as a temporary measure
another naive way that is not robust is instead of deleting just set stat.visible = false and return <></> for those - but that is just a quick hack for now until you figure out how to get unique ids and I don't recommend it for production

I use "index" because in my StatsResult when I fetch the result I call the onResult function. It needs an index to work otherwise it won't be able to know which result it should change. Apart from that, you're suggesting I should use the built-in React "key" property and change it accordingly when new elements are added/removed? A key that needs to be something custom, not just the index of the array (stats.length).

The cause of your rendering issue is definitely this key={index} even react says "Index as a key often leads to subtle and confusing bugs." - it should be key={something unique for each stat at all times - also cant be a random number } - doesn't matter why if you want it fixed change your on result logic - just read the whole page I linked - react docs explains it well

No when you add or delete non of the stat keys that remain should change - this change is whats causing your issue
